# JSON Object parsing problem in Android with Volley library

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, android-volley

I am trying to get JSON response from server and then display it in my android but failing to do so due to parsing error

my server response jsonformat= {
    "Result": "Login Success",
    "User_Name:": "Ayan"
}

But in android I can't ge the second object and it is returned as null

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh3Ew.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your response, you have the field like "User_Name:" or did you wrote the response wrong?

```
JsonObject object = new JsonObject(response);
String result = object.getString("Result");
String userName = object.getString("User_Name:");
```

check this @Ayan